# Django does not install model tables

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In my project, I have a routers.py with different router classes.  Now, I am making a new app.  I have created my models.py.  I have also registered the app in the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.  Then, I ran validate.  Everything is fine.  When I syncd thoughb, Django does not install the tables.  I tried using

```
python manage.py sqlall <app_name> | psql <database>
```

Then, I get an error message saying:

```
psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user <user name>
```

I noticed that the role does not exist in postgres.  So, I created the role with login privilege createdb and password.  Then, I get a different error message:

```
psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user <user name>
close failed in file object destructor:
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:
```

And, it does not provide the original exception.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Django application is unable to log onto the DB.

In django's `settings.py` make sure you have the proper DB credentials setup:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'HOST': get_env_variable("DJANGO_DB_HOST"),
    'NAME': get_env_variable("DJANGO_DB_NAME"),
    'USER': get_env_variable("DJANGO_DB_USER"),
    'PASSWORD': get_env_variable("DJANGO_DB_PWD"),
    'PORT': '',
    },
...
}
```

As you can see my credentials are grabbed from environment variables. You can hardcode them in for test purposes.

Then in the DB (mine is postgresql) create the user/grant it the correct privileges, for example:

```
ssh root@dbhost
su - postgres
createdb dbname
psql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE dbname TO dbuser
```

That should do.
I recommend the following steps as well, if they are missing from your setup:

In your app's `admin.py` register your models with Django's admin:

```
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Model1)
...
admin.site.register(ModelN)
```

Then, assuming you have created the project already, run:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

(it's the syncdb equivalent. Read the docs about [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/)).
If that command does not ask for the admin superuser then create your administrative user (i.e. the user who can manipulate the models through django's admin interface) with:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Fire up Django

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and see what happens whan you visit your site and admin at

```
localhost:8000/
localhost:8000/admin
```

Please pardon me if you know all those things already. That is what I normally do in my dev environment (I also use virtualenv, of course).